# How to query mongoose to find one thing or the other using the findOne method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to create a login system using mongoose to store the data. simply put... if a user model has both email and username fields, and i want to query the database to find if a new user signing up does not have the same email or username as an existing user??
basically something like this

```
 const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email || username: req.body.username })

      if(user){
        return "user already exists"
      }
```

so basically i am asking how can i find if the email already exists in the database OR the username already exits in the database?
Thank you for the help :}

Comment: $or will work perfectly fine in this case. Please check below URL https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/

Comment: why dont you check just the email? a email is usually unique

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$or` operator, try:

```
 const user = await User.findOne({ $or: [{ email: req.body.email }, { username: req.body.username }] })

      if(user){
        return "user already exists"
      }
```

For your [reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/). Hope it helps.